# Listen for updates in Firebase Realtime Database with REST in Unity WebGL

Tags: c#, firebase, rest, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have a WebGL app and since Firebase does not have plugin for Unity WebGL I am using REST and the basic GET call looks like this ( using Unity RestClient )

```
RestClient.Get($"https://rtdb.firebaseio.com/Users/{localUser_dbId}/partyID/.json").Then(response => { })
```

How can I implement listening to value changes in the database? Something like new message was added to chat etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get realtime updates through the REST API, you'll have to implement its [REST streaming](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming) protocol which is based on EventSource / Server-Sent Events.

To start this protocol, set the request's `Accept` header to  `text/event-stream`, which tells the server you want to receive SSE events instead of a regular REST response.

You'll then get all updates over a single connection/request, and send all write operations over separate connection.